# how to write regex to find all phone numbers in a .txt file?

Tags: java

I am trying to extract all phone number from a .txt file. The file has some text with different phone numbers that have different length and country code. An example from the file is

```
not every line has a number
6/24/21, 12:14 am - +98 905 460 1134 joined using this group's invite link
6/23/21, 5:09 pm - +973 3345 9934 joined using this group's invite link
6/23/21, 5:09 pm - +968 9931 9003:
```

What I did so far is

```
File file = new File("chat.txt");
            Scanner content = new Scanner(file);
            while(content.hasNext())
            {
                String line = content.nextLine();
                String patternString = "(\+[1-9]\d{0,2}[- ]?)?[1-9]\d{9}"; //pretty sure this is the issue
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                boolean matchFound = matcher.find(); //should return true if it finds a phone number
                if(matchFound){
                String phone = ; //substring the found phone number  
                // output or write in a new file
                }              
            }
```

What is missing is the pattern (regex) and the way to substring the phone number. Unfortunately, I could not find a solution to do so.
Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("chat.txt");
        String patternString = "\\+\\d{2,3}(?: \\d{3,4}){2,3}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        try (Scanner content = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (content.hasNext()) {
                String line = content.nextLine();
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println(matcher.group());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

is one way of doing it. Non-capturing group, with repetitions.

Comment: While this is correct, it would be a better answer if you explained what you did, so your answer will be more useful in general than just solving one person’s assignment.

Comment: I did explain it. But I should also add maybe that since there are no captured groups in the regex, the empty-parameter invocation of Matcher.group will give the entire match.

Comment: You explained it in a way people familiar with regular expressions will understand.  But I’m fairly certain that neither Ali nor most people who come to this question in the future seeking the same answer will be in that group, so a more detailed explanation would be useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Everything is clear but as VGR suggested, can you please explain how did you come up with the regex? because I am kinda new to this concept and some numbers are not being extracted (not sure why) (+966 59 566 3243) for example . Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well the trouble is, I'm not entirely sure how US phone numbers work, For the one that 'escaped' you could try to relax the constraints a little. Look at the length constraints and play around a bit

Comment: Look at the length constraints and play around a bit `String patternString = "\\+\\d{2,3}(?: \\d+)+";` will relax for arbitrary number of groups of arbitrary length

Comment: Thanks again! the problem was that I did not kwon the structure of the patterns in general, I changed the length and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

To find the string use:

```
if(matcher.find()){
    String phone = matcher.group(1); 
    // output or write in a new file
}
```

An example regex which should work is:

```
^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3,14}$
```